# sed gives error with unterminated substitute in regular expression

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I trying to substitute string "x.x.x.x" in a file and output the results to another file. It is giving me error unterminated substitute in regular expression

here is the code

```
sed 's/x.x.x.x/'$bigip_management_ip'/g' temp.tt >> variables.tf
sed: 1: "s/x.x.x.x/": unterminated substitute in regular expression
```

echo $bigip_management_ip

```
54.83.174.153
```

shitole$ cat temp.tt

```
variable "bigip_management_ip" {
  default = "x.x.x.x"
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a MCVE for your problem:

```
bigip_management_ip=" 54.83.174.153"
sed 's/x.x.x.x/'$bigip_management_ip'/g'
```

When executed on macOS, you get:

```
sed: 1: "s/x.x.x.x/": unterminated substitute in regular expression
```

The problem is the leading space in the variable causing word splitting due to a lack of quoting. ShellCheck warns about this:

```
In /Users/myuser/myscript line 2:
    sed 's/x.x.x.x/'$bigip_management_ip'/g'
                    ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.
```

You should always quote your variables unless you're sure you can't:

```
sed "s/x.x.x.x/$bigip_management_ip/g"
```

Comment: Thanks when I do sed "s/x.x.x.x/$bigip_management_ip/g" temp.tt >> variables.tf  with double quotes I still see blank space ? how i can get rid  off it ?    cat variables.tf 
`variable "bigip_management_ip" {
  default = " 54.83.174.153"
}`

Comment: @SanjayShitole The space is in your variable. When you ask to replace `x.x.x.x` with the contents of a variable, obviously the space is included. You should fix it wherever you assign the variable, or strip it with `"s/x.x.x.x/${bigip_management_ip# }/g"`

Comment: I ended up by extracting it to a variable, then `sed "$sed_opts"`.

Answer (score 6):

Just change your command like below, it is working for me.

```
sed 's|'x.x.x.x'|'"$bigip_management_ip"'|g' temp.tt >> variables.tf
```

Comment: `sed 's|'x.x.x.x'|'"$bigip_management_ip"'|g' temp.tt >> variables.tf ` it worked `variable "bigip_management_ip" {
  default = " 54.83.174.153"
}`

Comment: @SanjayShitole, What do you want say? It is not clear here.

Comment: somehow when I open the file I see "54.172.214.31^[[0m"  instead in vi  editor instead of "54.172.214.31" not sure why its adding extra character, those are not seen if I do cat cat variables.tf 
variable "bigip_management_ip" {
  default = "54.172.214.31"
}

Comment: dos2unix did not work dos2unix variables.tf
dos2unix: Binary symbol 0x1B found at line 2
dos2unix: Skipping binary file variables.tf

Comment: do that in file temp.tt  not with variable.tf

Answer (score -3):

```sh
sed s/x\\.x\\.x\\.x/\\$bigip_management_ip/g
```

Comment: You should explain your answer, code only answers are less useful for new users.

Comment: Can you explain why you think this is a good answer?  What difference do the backslashes before the dots make?  Did you mean to use `s/x\\.x\\.x\\.x/…/` (or perhaps `'s/x\.x\.x\.x/…/'`)?  Why do you have a backslash before the dollar symbol (what is the benefit of that)?  Generally, you'd do best to enclose the `sed` script (the actual program) inside quotes — single quotes unless you need variable substitution: `sed "s/x\\.x\\.x\\.x/$bigip_management_ip/"`.